# "could not be resolved as a type" in multiple regression in org.apache.commons.math.stat

Tags: java

I am getting an error when i try to use the multiple regression feature in the org.apache.commons.math.stat.

In my program, i have

```
import org.apache.commons.math.stat.regression.*;
```

But when i refer to the ordinary least square function in my program as

```
OLSMultipleLinearRegression regression2 = new OLSMultipleLinearRegression();
```

It gave me an error saying that:

> OLSMultipleLinearRegression could not be resolved as a type.

I think i am missing some important point in my program, Please help me if you know what i am missing.

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest commons from:
[Latest Commons: my last view - 17.11.2013](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi),

Right click on the project, then Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries, add the commons-math3-3.2.jar to libraries.

Then in your .java file import OLSMultipleLinearRegression from the new library.

```
    import org.apache.commons.math3.stat.regression.OLSMultipleLinearRegression;
```